# Running time Functions for nested for-loop

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

for the following nested for-loops I am in trouble to compute running time functions.
1-
`for(int i = 1 ; i <= N ; i++)
   for(int j = 1 ; j * j <= N ; j *= 2);`

2-
`for(int i = 2 ; i <= N ; i *= i);`

3-
`for(int i = 1 ; i <= N ; i++)
   for(int j = 1 ; j <= i ; j++)
     for(int k = 1 ; k <= j ; k++);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guesses:

1. `O( N * log(sqrt(N)) )`
2. Doesn't have closed form expression because of:

> [indefinite integral of x^x] cannot be expressed in terms of a finite number of elementary functions... [[1]](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html#eqn27)

3. `O( N^3 )`